# Trim Macro gets error

Tags: excel, trim, vba

I cant figure out this line `For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Cells` I keep getting error `Method 'worksheet' range failed`

Thanks

Edit: updated

```
Sub trimAll()
Dim ws As Worksheets
Dim c As Range

For Each ws In WorkSheets
    If ws.Name = "XXX" Or ws.Name = "YYY" Then
       For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Cells
           If Not (IsEmpty(c) Or IsError(c)) Then
              c.Value = Trim(c.Value)
           End If
       Next c
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: If **XXX** and **YYY** are valid worksheet objects, there shouldn't be any problem in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `For Each ws in Worksheets` because the Sheets collection can contain things which aren't worksheets

Comment: Good point! I should modify my own standard practise to skip over macro sheets, charts, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help barrowc but I still get the same error

Comment: Above code already filters the sheets by the `If statement` which I'm sure @Tim identified as a valid worksheet object.

Comment: It seems to be working now, not sure what was going wrong last time I tryed it, Thank you